# Efficient Immutable Map Implementation?

Tags: functional-programming, dictionary, immutability, performance

I'm wondering if there is an implementation of a map which is:

- **Immutable**, so that I can use it in
  functional programming, and
  effortlessly ensure transactions and concurrency.
- **Fast**. I've checked out Binary
  Search Trees (RB, AVL) and Tries, but
  none of them seemed to be as fast as
  Hash Tables. Is there a map
  implementation that supports constant time
  for updates and retrievals? (or at least *very* fast logarithmic time)

In short, is there a functional data structure that can compare with Hash Maps in performance?

Answer (score 4):

Clojure has immutable maps. ([link](http://clojure.org/functional_programming)). Not sure what underlying data structure it is using. Clojure source code will give you more information!

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful response. I'm going to check out Clojure soon.

Comment: Clojure's immutable maps use 32-way hash array mapped tries (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_array_mapped_trie). They are a great data structure - almost as fast a mutable HashMap, but with all the advantages of being persistent and immutable.

Answer (score 3):

Scala also has [immutable maps](http://www.drmaciver.com/2008/08/new-collections-in-scala-272/), but they are slower than hash tables. I suspect the answer to your question is no, you won't find an immutable map implementation with O(1) expected time insert/query operations.

Comment: Yea, I'm currently experimenting with Scala, and generally not satisfied with performance.

Answer (score 1):

Anyway just to share with people, these are two interesting blog entries about Persistent Vectors implementation in Scala using Tries. They also mention Clojure's implementation, as well as the new IntMap in recent Scala releases.

http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/implementing-persistent-vectors-in-scala
http://www.codecommit.com/blog/scala/more-persistent-vectors-performance-analysis

For these data structures, I have tested with key as integers, but not yet strings. Because my real application is gonna use strings as keys, I'm not sure if the implementation will be more efficient than a Hash Map. What if I use the HashCode of the String as a key, then use a Persistent Vector to support the map? I will use a 32-way trie to implement the Persistent Vector. I guess collision would be very rare, and memory would only be spent accordingly. But I'm not sure about the actual amount needed copying on updates.

I'm gonna post my results soon.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't read it, but I think some people consider [Purely Functional Data Structures](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521663504) as the bible for this kind of thing.

Comment: Doesn't have anything about maps/hashtables.